# yii2 Useage of user identity in index page

Tags: security, authentication, yii2

In yii2 is it save to use the instance of yii2 identity in index page. For instance:

```
Yii::$app->user->idnetity->user_fname;
```

Does this compromise on its security if I use this in view page or is it safe to use??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php function are performed  server side  ..  so  this part of code is not in client browser ..

in client browser  eventually you send an echo  of the result  eg:

```
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->username
```

In this way in the browser is only showed the name of the user  nothing others

Comment: Now I understand... Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "safe to use" but in general you can safely display anything as long as it's sanitized (especially if it comes from user's input).
Usually it's enough to use `encode()` method from Html Helper.

```
<?php echo \yii\helpers\Html::encode(\Yii::$app->user->identity->user_fname); ?>
```

If you are not sure if user is logged in or not in this `view` it's good to check:

```
<?php if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest): ?>
Welcome Guest!
<?php else: ?>
Hello, <?= \yii\helpers\Html::encode(\Yii::$app->user->identity->user_fname); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```